# Searching for String pattern in Generic List collection

Tags: .net, list, generics

I have a Generic List of String of filenames. I would like to grab only that values that match a specific pattern. I looked for some documentation on finding patterns within a List and found this MSDN article.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc%28VS.85%29.aspx#Y1440

I have cut some of the basic example and listed it here.

```
List<string> dinosaurs = new List<string>();

dinosaurs.Add("Compsognathus");
dinosaurs.Add("Amargasaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("Oviraptor");
dinosaurs.Add("Velociraptor");
dinosaurs.Add("Deinonychus");
dinosaurs.Add("Dilophosaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("Gallimimus");
dinosaurs.Add("Triceratops");

// Search predicate returns true if a string ends in "saurus".
private static bool EndsWithSaurus(String s)
{
    if ((s.Length > 5) && 
        (s.Substring(s.Length - 6).ToLower() == "saurus"))
    {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

Bool result = dinosaurs.Find(EndsWithSaurus);
```

I think I understand what is being done with ONE BIG exception. The method `EndsWithSaurus` is expecting a String to be passed in to it, yet I don't see where it is being pased in

Comment: Sorry. I should have mentioned this. I am using .NET v3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're on .NET 3.5+ (using LINQ extension methods in the System.Linq namespace), you could do this which will return your subset of matches:

```
var results = dinosaurs.Where(d => d.EndsWith("saurus")).ToList();
```

To answer your other questions in regards to the example shown, first of all Find() only returns true/false if it locates a match, but not the matches themselves.  Where() on the other hand, returns the subset that matches.  I like LINQ for these types of queries (Where(), etc) because they work with any `IEnumerable` container (List, HashSet, Array, etc).

As to your question on how the string gets passed, the Find() method (and Where(), etc) take a delegate `Func<string, bool>` - since your list is a string container - that tells whether it matches or not, the example you showed passes in the name of the method, which assigns it to the delegate.  This works as long as the method satisfies the signature of `Func<string, bool>` which means it takes a string and returns a bool.

Make sense?

Comment: p.s.  the ToList() is just if you want to store the results in a list, you could also just enumerate over it directly if you prefer with a foreach, or use ToArray() to store in an array, etc, etc, etc...

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Does the `Find` method always use the same delegate signature Function<string, bool> or is the delegate signature somehow defined by the user?

Comment: It's always dependent on the type of the collection, so if the collection is IEnumerable<T> the delegate is Func<T, bool>.  So if the collection contains int, the delegate must take an int, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the `Find` method as a looping through each value in the `List` that calls the `delegate` that you passed.

Note, it does not return `bool`. It returns the generic type of the `List`.

Basically, you could write your own:

```
string Find(List<string> dinosaurs)
{
    for (string dinosaur in dinosaurs)
    {
        if (EndsWithSaurus(dinosaur))
        {
            return dinosaur;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```